# HTML Не отображаются картинки находящиеся каталогом выше

Tags: html, path

Хочу добавить картинку которая находится на каталог выше html документа

```
  <img src="../photo_B.png" height="100" width="100" />
```

Если запустить html файл из ide, то картинка не отображается и ее адрес становится

```
http://127.0.0.1:5500/photo_B.png
```

Если навести на код элемента, то напишет "не удалось загрузить изображения".
Если же запустить html документ просто из папки тогда все будет отображаться.
Также, если положить картинку не каталогом выше, а рядом с html или каталогом ниже, то проблем не возникает.

Как сделать так чтобы при запуске из иде картинка отображалась?
Пробовал разные пути:

```
../photo_B.png
/../photo_B.png
./../photo_B.png
```

Comment: Вероятно вы пользуетесь сборщиком, например Gulp, у него настроена корневая папка, например dist, и эта папка для него http://127.0.0.1:5500. Он просто не в состоянии прыгнуть выше головы ))

Comment: Я запускаю html документ из pycharm, так же запускал из vs code с помощью расширения live server.

Comment: У них есть сборщики и для них корневой папкой является та, которая открыта в рабочей области, думаю как-то так.

Comment: Ну неужели никто в иде никогда не делает путь до картинки наверх?)

Comment: Я б сказал что все делают в иде, но никто через нее не запускает. Так как пользуются сборщиками.

Comment: Мне просто нужно сверстать html и кинуть его на почту. И в общем на почте картинки не отображаются :(